# Mapeamento de View com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Estou com dúvida de como fazer o mapeamento de um View criada no Banco Oracle 11G com Fluent-API.

Segue um trecho da view com alias:

```
tran.id_transporte AS "ID Navio",
tran.ds_nome_transporte AS "Navio",
pemb.id_porto AS "ID Porto Embarque",
pemb.ds_porto AS "Porto Embarque",
temb.id_terminal AS "ID Terminal",
```

No mapeamento fiz da seguinte forma:

```
        public VWProgramacaoEmbarque_Mapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.IdTerminal);
        this.ToTable("VW_PROGRAMACAO");

        this.Property(t => t.IdNavio).HasColumnName("ID_TRANSPORTE");
        this.Property(t => t.Navio).HasColumnName("DS_NOME_TRANSPORTE");
        this.Property(t => t.IdPortoEmbarque).HasColumnName("ID_PORTO");
        this.Property(t => t.PortoEmbarque).HasColumnName("DS_PORTO");
        this.Property(t => t.IdTerminal).HasColumnName("ID_TERMINAL");
    }
```

No Oracle consigo realizar a consulta de uma coluna com alias.

```
select distinct("ID Navio") from vw_programacao;
```

Na minha aplicação estou realizando a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
var idNavios = Context.VWProgramacao.Select(e => e.IdNavio).Distinct();
```

Mas gera o seguinte erro:

> {"ORA-00904: \"Extent1\".\"ID_TRANSPORTE\": identificador inválido"}

Acredito que seja por causa do meu mapeamento que esteja errado ou talvez seja por causa do alias da minha view.

Alguma ideia do que possa ser? onde estou errando?

Comment: Se tu estás a expor a view com esses alias, não tens a coluna ID_TRANSPORTE, mas sim ID Navio (Muito cuidado com esses espaços, não recomendo nada fazer isso). E substituir para o valor correcto em todas essas properties.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso Essa view foi criada por outro setor onde trabalho, nesse caso na minha aplicação o nome da minha coluna fica ...HasColumnName("ID NAVIO"); ?

Comment: Sim. Nessas linhas de código, estás a associar a propriedade do teu objecto à coluna da tabela /view. Neste caso, a tua view tem como nomes de colunas esses alias.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso Entendi, irei alterar e fazer o teste novamente.

Comment: Não se mapeia view com o EF e sim tabelas.. você poder fazer um select que retorne tudo que você precisar com elas.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso Retirei minha resposta para priorizar a sua, se tiver interesse de responder uma solução com base no que disse, irei aceitar, pois funcionou como falou.

Comment: @samuelrvg, já coloquei como resposta. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tu estás a expor a view com esses alias, não tens a coluna ID_TRANSPORTE, mas sim ID Navio (Muito cuidado com esses espaços, não recomendo nada fazer isso). E substituir para o valor correcto em todas essas properties.

Answer (score 1):

Este erro se dá porque você sua `VIEW` não possui a coluna `ID_TRANSPORTE`, talvez na hora que você a criou você tenha colocado:

Veja que você colocou essa COLUNA como "ID Navio"

> tran.id_transporte AS "ID Navio"

Então na hora de mapear para o Entity, você precisaria por o nome do "ALIAS" e não da COLUNA em si, ou se você retirar os apelidos ai sim poderá por o nome das COLUNAS.

Por exemplo, seu mapeamento deveria ficar assim:

### SUA VIEW

```
tran.id_transporte AS "ID Navio",
tran.ds_nome_transporte AS "Navio",
pemb.id_porto AS "ID Porto Embarque",
pemb.ds_porto AS "Porto Embarque",
temb.id_terminal AS "ID Terminal",
```

### SEU MAPEAMENTO TERIA QUE FICAR ASSIM

```
public VWProgramacaoEmbarque_Mapping()
{
    this.HasKey(t => t.IdTerminal);
    this.ToTable("VW_PROGRAMACAO");

    this.Property(t => t.IdNavio).HasColumnName("ID Navio");
    this.Property(t => t.Navio).HasColumnName("Navio");
    this.Property(t => t.IdPortoEmbarque).HasColumnName("ID Porto Embarque");
    this.Property(t => t.PortoEmbarque).HasColumnName("Porto Embarque");
    this.Property(t => t.IdTerminal).HasColumnName("ID Terminal");
}
```

Precisaria usar os "ALIAS", se caso você for mapear usando os nomes das COLUNAS simplesmente não precisaria por os Apelidos.